# Change string to datetime with PM/AM

Tags: pandas, datetime

I have a pandas data frame column with the following format:
`30-APR-19 09.47.43.019000 PM`
and I want to convert it to a Datetime format of the following type:
`30-APR-19 21.47.43.019000`

So far I am using the following code:
`df['DateTime']=pd.to_datetime(df['DialogDateTime'],format='%d-%b-%y %H.%M.%S.%f %p')`
but is not working. Moreover, I have also tried the following:
`df['DateTime']=pd.to_datetime(df['DialogDateTime'],format='%d-%b-%y %H.%M.%S.%f %p').dt.strftime(date_format='%H.%M.%S.%f')`
without any success as well.
Any help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `%I` for match hours:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DialogDateTime':['30-APR-19 09.47.43.019000 PM',
                                     '30-APR-19 10.47.43.019000 PM']})
df['DateTime'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['DialogDateTime'],format='%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%S.%f %p')
                  .dt.strftime(date_format='%d-%b-%y %H.%M.%S.%f %p') )
print (df)
                 DialogDateTime                      DateTime
0  30-APR-19 09.47.43.019000 PM  30-Apr-19 21.47.43.019000 PM
1  30-APR-19 10.47.43.019000 PM  30-Apr-19 22.47.43.019000 PM
```